# Filter files in HTML file open dialog

Tags: javascript, html, fileopendialog

I am working with file upload to the server using HTML tag:

```
<input type="file">
```

When I click on the browse button it shows me a file open dialog. Can I filter the files by passing the extension filter to that dialog? Like we can do in .Net framework's file open dialog by passing some thing like:

```
Text files *.txt|.txt
```

Using this filter we can only open `.txt` files. Other files not shown to the user. Is there any option for this dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Standard

Actually in HTML5 you can set the `accept` attribute so now this is possible! The [W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#attr-input-accept) states:

> The **accept** attribute may be specified to provide user agents with a hint of what file types will be accepted.

### Accepted values [[Full list in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type#List_of_common_media_types)]

Just pass a valid [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type) to the attribute for example:

- `audio/*`
- `video/*`

  - `video/ogg`
- `image/*`

  - `image/jpg`
  - `image/bmp`

### Example code

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Answer (score 2):

> my question is, can i filter the files by passing the extension filter to that dialog?

No you can't do this with the plain `type="file"` input. You could use some [Flash upload controls](http://www.uploadify.com/) though that allow you to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't  think you can edit this dialog options, but you can validate the file after the user select it.

tO edit the dialog, I remember that you can do that by a flash or Silverlight uploaders, such as swfUpload.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of code that I came up with when I was in need of filtering some of the file types:

```
<input type="file" accept=".xls, .xlsx, .csv" placeholder="File to be upload" />
```

Accept attribute supports multiple files comma separated.